# How can I code monero mining algorithm from scratch?

Tags: mining, algorithm

I want to code a javascript-based monero mining algorithm from scratch. However, I couldn't find any training set, lectures, courses, books, etc. about it.

How can I code a javascript based monero mining algorithm from scratch?

Comment: Please review the Help, in particular: https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask (e.g. "Your questions should be reasonably scoped").

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is documented here: [doc/specs.md](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/5bb4c7760d999044c1728fabd9310cd96ce02cee/doc/specs.md)

Note that implementing in *javascript* would be a largely pointless exercise due to the fact it will run horrendously slowly, in part due to native javascript not having the rounding modes as defined by the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Is there a sample training set, documents, book, etc. that teaches coding the algorithm I mentioned?

Comment: The [document](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/5bb4c7760d999044c1728fabd9310cd96ce02cee/doc/specs.md) I mentioned has all the detail needed to implement the algorithm. Teaching "coding" is outside of the scope.